# matlab multiple plots sizes

Tags: matlab, plot, size, width

I have question regarding width and height of Plots. If we have multiple plots in same figure how can we set the size for each plot on our own.

Also is there a way to have multiple plots without using subplots?

Comment: Width and height of the plot. I want to insert 4 plots in same figure.

Comment: at its core, `subplot` simply call `axes` to create a new axis. You could do that yourself, and specify whatever position you want: `axes('Units','pixels', 'Position',[x y w h])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with subplots (calling `subplot` returns you an axes handle).  Then set the `Position` property on each subplot axes handle.

Create all the subplots before you start moving them, because creating a subplot afterwards will automatically remove any existing subplot that overlaps the default location of the new one.